# How to express appreciation for an offer of science research funding

Tags: funding, communication, science

What is an acceptable way to state that you are very happy to have been offered funding for a research proposal?

"I am honored to have this offer of funding for my research"
"I am grateful for this offer..."
etc

Neither of those sound right to me -- research funding is about having a sound and interesting proposal, so feeling honored or grateful doesn't ring true to me.  I've been wondering this for a while but I now have a research fellowship offer I need to decline (already took an earlier offer) so I want to make sure my declination does not sound unappreciative.

I know this issue may seem simple or pedestrian to some, but I'd like to know how most would reply to know I'm meeting the expectations of program officers, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: You're overthinking it. "I really appreciate the offer" is fine.

Comment: Don't start with a long appreciation at the beginning as it may lead the reader to expect an acceptance. Just a short sentence on how you appreciated their recognition, and immediately tell the news neutrally. Simply state the fact that you have pursued another opportunity and hence have to decline their offer. No need to explain any pros and cons, keep it short and professional; end with a thank you. What they really would appreciate is applicants informing them with the decision in a timely manner so that they can move on to the other quickly; so do that soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just say something like. "Thank you very much for your offer of funding, I am extremely grateful.  Unfortunately I have already accepted another offer which is not compatible, so I must decline your offer."

The important thing is to **show respect for the agency by replying as soon as you can**, so that another deserving candidate can get the funding.  Don't worry that much about the phrasing, everyone knows these things happen, just be polite.

Answer (score 2):

> I received your offer for research funding. While I am honored and
>   greatly appreciate your offer, I must regrettably decline as I have
>   accepted another source of funding.
>
> Thank you for your kind consideration.
>
> [salutation, like Sincerely]
>
> [signed]

Keep it simple, short, polite, and professional. If you are in a country where overstatement is important, throw in a "very" and/or a "deeply" to conform to your norms.

You might want something more personal only if someone was literally offering to write you a personal check to pay for your research out of their own account. Otherwise accepting/declining an offer (and applying to multiple programs which all have the same deadlines) is the norm - so don't worry about it.

Simple, short, polite, and professional.

Comment: A salutation is the thing at the start of the letter (e.g., "Dear Professor Yaffle,"). "Sincerely" and its friends are _valedictions_.